# AC vacuum held at 24in for 5 hrs at elevation 6K' but dropped after 12 additional hours to 16in

Tags: ac

AC was not working.  I changed the compressor and replaced a few O-rings after using UV dye to locate possible leaks.

I have read that a vacuum should hold for about 30 minutes. My vacuum held for 5 hours at 24 in. (I'm at 6,ooo' of elevation.) When I checked it in the morning, it was reading 16 in. I'm using a new Robinair vacuum pump.

Any suggestions as to what would cause this or should I trust that the leaks have been taken care of.

Comment: Did you put pag oil on the new o-rings during assembly or just place them dry?

Comment: Are you testing the vacuum with the engine running or after it has been turned off?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Regarding the 'O' rings, I used oil on most of them; as for the question on the vacuum, it must be checked with the engine off, which I did.  Actually I went ahead with completing the process.  Air is coming out cold but will check it again tomorrow.